# macOS Ventura “Share Menu” in Safari is not working. Any steps to take to remedy?

Tags: macos

When trying to access the share menu across macOS and various applications I'm always presented with a spinner.

What are some items I can check that might be preventing the menu from loading correctly?

[image: screenshot of the share menu]

Comment: Check for any Extensions in System Settings > Privacy & Security > Extensions, and try removing them.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I've tried a few times rebooting and doing a force close etc.

Comment: @benwiggy I've unchecked all the extensions in the settings panel with no luck.

Comment: Thanks, @Giacomo1968, I just ran it Saturday hoping that would clear up the issue. I was looking to see if there were any similar tools or any of the individual tools built in Onyx that might help.